Can I Install a patio roof ledger board to studs above second floor rim joist?
I’m looking to build a covered deck that’s attached to the back of my house.  The trouble is that to get the height I need for my roof slope, I need to attach the ledger board for the roof about 18” above the rim joist for the second floor.  I had thought about a couple options:
1: install a standard ledger to the rim joist, and then install another ledger to the studs above it, and add structural support between the 2.
2: Install 6x6 posts right on the house to support the ledger, and use an LVL for it (since I’ve got a 20’ span).
The covered space is 20’x15’ with the 20’ side attached to the house.  I had planned on an lvl beam halfway (7.5’) to support 2x6 exposed rafters then T&G above that.
Thanks!
